# If using DateDiff function, using the interval "yyyy", is the function simply subtracting the difference between the year value of date1 and date2?

Tags: vba, datediff

Macro does not appear to be taking days into account when calculating a person's age.

```
Sub alcohol_test()
    Dim strBirthday As Date

    strBirthday = CDate(InputBox("Input date of birth to be verified: ", "Date of Birth"))
    If DateDiff("yyyy", strBirthday, Date) < 21 Then MsgBox ("Customer underage, sale of alcohol illegal.") _
    Else MsgBox ("Age Confirmed: Alcohol may be sold")

End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't asking it to do check if the age is over 21 but checking what year they were born but if this year is 21 years after that year. `A = "01/04/1998"` and `Msgbox DateAdd("yyyy", 21, A)` and `If CDbl(DateAdd("yyyy", 21, A)) < CDbl(Now()) then msgbox "Old Enough"`

Comment: In Australia that needs to be 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is even worse:
When comparing December 31th to January 1st of the immediately succeeding year,
`DateDiff` for Year ("yyyy") returns 1, even though only a single day has elapsed, says [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function).

So you better compare two dates, e. g. if the birthday was before the day 21 years ago.

```
Dim datBirthday as Date
datBirthday = CDate(InputBox("Input date of birth to be verified: ", "Date of Birth"))
If datBirthday < DateSerial(Year(Date) - 21, Month(Date), Day(Date)) Then
```

I changed the variable name, as a beginning with "str" is a little misleading when you use date values.

Comment: Thank you very much, Vielen Dank!